# How do I restore a missing file /private/ect/hosts

Tags: filesystems, restore

I deleted an application from my mac,and went to the library to delete anything there with adobe on it.!

Now when I have tried to find my/private/ect/hosts folder from my finder,  it says that it cannot be found. How can I restore it? Have I deleted it. It was there before

Any advice on how to restore it please..

Comment: Are you sure your looking in the correct directory?  You can also just undelete the file, since it should be in your recycle bin, or the OS X equivalent.

Comment: You should be able to restore it from your Time Machine backup.

Comment: `/private/etc/hosts` is a file, not a folder.

Comment: @Barmar - please try to add useful information, not speculation. If the OP used the wrong path, the file would not be found, using the correct path... we have yet to see...

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.OK I AM kicking myself in the proverbial butt. I can't believe I made such a simple mistake, 'ect' instead of 'etc'. I did a system restore, done numerous attempts  on the terminal at trying to re-paste the fie contents in my system, and all along it was there! Sorry, and massive thanks to Tetsujin for noticing!!!

Answer (score 0):

the folder is etc not ect

Open a new finder window, hit Cmd/Shift/G then paste /private/etc/hosts & Go.

If you want to edit it, drag it to the desktop, edit in TextEdit then drag it back. Reboot so it will use the new version.

*[Can be done in Terminal, but this is simpler]*

Comment: It's a file, not a folder, so you can't go there with `Cmd-Shift-G`.

Comment: Did you try it before posting that reply? My guess would be.... 'no'

Comment: _The folder "hosts" can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents_. It works if I change to `/private/etc`.

Comment: Let's not turn this into a discussion. If you follow my answer, you can edit hosts.

Comment: Maybe it's version-dependent. I'm on Snow Leopard.

Comment: out of date OS == idk.